# PHP script can't be found or is unable to stat

Tags: php

Everything had been working fine, I have an iOS app that makes a call to a server with PHP scripts that it interacts with, but then this morning in the error logs I find this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVsjK.jpg

Any help is greatly appreciated as this has grinded everything to a hault.

Comment: Are you still using PHP4? You should upgrade. PHP 4.4 was deprecated **6 years ago** http://php.net/eol.php Upgrade to PHP 5.4 or newer.

Comment: I'm using PHP 5 to the best of my knowledge, I upgraded it a while ago. @user3791372 Thanks I'll start making my way through those steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it nice to wake up to a string of error messages and a dead server. Without more details, I'd say you've been attacked, and need to

1. updgrade php urgently,
2. check php, database and webserver logs thoroughly
3. check html output for malicious javascript on all sites hosted on server (check head and the foot of the html code),
4. check validity of php code on all php files in server - check for includes that shouldn't be there, encoded code that looks suspicious. This latter type of code will blantely stick out,
5. grab a coffee or two - actually, that should have been #1.
6. Once all this is done, check your php code for vulnerabilities. Don't assume that the only users who hit the php code are iOS users so add all necessary sanity checks. Consider programming like you use double/nay triple condoms.

Chances are, you may have had a schoolboy script attack, but that doesn't mean stuff isn't damaged. You do have backups, right?

Comment: Thanks for this dude. In terms of backups I assume you mean all of my code, in which case yes I do. What am I looking for in the PHP db, and webserver logs? And in terms of sanity checks?? Only on of my PHP scripts is in the web root, all the others are scattered in different places outside the webroot to prevent people getting access to them.

Comment: @Mr.P You're looking for malicious activity, such as requests to php forms that your app doesn't / shouldn't send, or requests that just feel out of place. Sanity checks is checking that data you get is what you expect, e.g. string length, strings that contain numbers, strings that are in an array of accepted values etc. Don't forget to upvote the answer as this is useful to you and accept as an aswer if it helps you. A backup is of your whole system, not just files - it prevents having to rebuild your system in the case of attacks. Determine what file is causing that error, and work backwards

Comment: OK, everything's working again. I still haven't combed through all the log files, but I 100% will. In terms of preventing this from happening again, any tips? You've been extremely helpful so far @user3791372

Comment: Tips would be to hit google for basic server maintainance if your server is self-managed.  You only need the basics to put you in a good position.

Comment: Will do, thanks again, invaluable help!